# Error mapping home directory with a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory, system-administration

I'm using a script to create new users and everything is working fine. However, when I try to log in with a user created with this script, I get the following error:

```
A Problem has occurred and your network home directory is not available.

This may be because a network file server is offline.

You have been logged on with a temporary home drive (H:) which may be shared
with other users.
```

The script creates the user and applies the correct permissions as far as I can tell.

Here's the script:

```
# Import active directory module for running AD cmdlets
Import-Module activedirectory

#Store the data from ADUsers.csv in the $ADUsers variable
$ADUsers = Import-csv .\Create_Staff_Accounts.csv

#Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file 
foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
    #Read user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a variable as below

    $Username   = $User.username
    $Password   = $User.password
    $Firstname  = $User.firstname
    $Lastname   = $User.lastname
    $OU         = $User.ou #This field refers to the OU the user account is to be created in
    $group      = $User.group
    $title      = $User.title
    $start      = $User.start
    $Homedrive  = "H:"
    $UserRoot = "\\servername\st$\"
    $HomeDirectory = $UserRoot + $Username

    #Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
    {
         #If user does exist, give a warning
         Write-Warning "A user account with username $Username already exists in Active Directory."
    }
    else
    {
        #User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account

        #Account will be created in the OU provided by the $OU variable read from the CSV file
        New-ADUser `
            -SamAccountName $Username `
            -Name "$Firstname $Lastname" `
            -UserPrincipalName "$($username)@domain.local" `
            -GivenName $Firstname `
            -Surname $Lastname `
            -Enabled $True `
            -DisplayName "$Firstname $Lastname" `
            -Path $OU `
            -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force) `
            -Homedrive $Homedrive `
            -HomeDirectory $HomeDirectory `
            -ScriptPath "logonscript.bat" `
            -Description "Staff Account:  $($title) from: $($start)"
             #-ChangePasswordAtLogon $True `



        #Now create the home folder and set modify permissions
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $Username
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity groupname -Members $Username
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity groupname -Members $Username
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "\\servername\st$\$($User.username)"
        $path = Get-Item -Path "\\servername\st$\$($User.username)"
        $acl = (Get-Item $path).GetAccessControl('Access')
        $AR = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Username, 'Modify', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
        $acl.SetAccessRule($AR)
        Set-Acl -Path $Path -AclObject $acl
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help and support.

Comment: Have you tried using the FQDN for the server?

Comment: I've actually changed the domain name to post it on here, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you Write-Host the share path from the script can the user manually map to that path?

Comment: If you check the folder's ACL itself after the folder has been created, does it look correct? Does the user AD object also look correct for the HomeDrive and Path?